# Can't get the meaning of "score mondo points"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm stuck with understanding the following sentence from [Effective Modern C++: 42 Specific Ways to Improve Your Use of C++11 and C++14](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=rjhIBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA16&lpg=PA16&dq=yes,%20the%20syntax%20looks%20toxic,%20but%20knowing%20it%20will%20score%20you%20mondo%20points%20with%20those%20few%20souls%20who%20care.&source=bl&ots=Fl4KW5yAmR&sig=fGpwVztBXBLJW75_Ijkg2aahEmA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiE1N7r5LfRAhUJqY8KHWS5CrMQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=yes%2C%20the%20syntax%20looks%20toxic%2C%20but%20knowing%20it%20will%20score%20you%20mondo%20points%20with%20those%20few%20souls%20who%20care.&f=false)

> yes, the syntax looks toxic, but knowing it will score you mondo points with those few souls who care.

1. What are these mysterious "mondo points"? I googled it and it relates to shoe size which seems kind of weird.
2. Do I understand correctly that these points are represented by souls? I also found that there is a phrasal verb "score with" which means to please somebody or someone. So in this case, *knowing* will *score with* (please) *few souls* and *you* is now irrelevant?

Comment: I think "mondo points", here, is just another way of saying "brownie points", and a brownie point is just _an imaginary award given to someone who does good deeds or attempts to please._

Comment: Wiktionary answers this question.

Comment: In college we used the term "mondo" to apply to a certain type of slightly coarse type of white guy who's fashion and priorities belied a less elite class viewpoint than those kids who had parents in the Junior league, went to dance cotillion growing up etc...The term only applied to guys from that particular white subsegment group that lived "big", drove a camaro or a motorcyle, perhaps wore their hair as a mullet, listened to loud hard rock.  I'm not sure if that was a very(extremely perhaps) local slang or if it was used elsewhere

Comment: Hard to believe, but I stumbled on this question for exactly the same reason: that book! Anyway in Italian we often use _un mondo di_ (which means _a world of_) in place of _a lot of/very much/..._ depending on the specific sentence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mondo is slang for very or extremely.  The entire sentence is very informal and has some other elements of programmer jargon or slang.

Re-written more formally, it would be:

> yes, the syntax looks bad, but knowing it will get you a lot of credit and appreciation from the few people who care.

[mondo](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mondo) (MW)

> extremely (slang)

Comment: I just searched Google Books for ["mondo points"](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB712GB712&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22mondo+points%22&start=10), and was well into the second page of results before I found an instance reflecting the sense ***mondo = many*** (which was in fact OP's very citation). Nearly all the rest referred to [Most downhill ski boots are sized in what is known as Mondopoint sizing, which measures the length of your foot from heel to big toe in centimeters.](http://www.skibootsizingcharts.com/history-of-mondopoint.php)

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear with "mondo". But what about scoring and souls? Seems like the word "along" is missing, right? "yes, the syntax looks toxic, but knowing it will score you mondo points ALONG with those few souls who care."

Comment: Not along with.  "The few souls who care will esteem you highly because you understand this syntax".  "score points with someone" means "Someone will award you points".

Comment: And one more question, please. Is it possible to say "it will score HIM points with them"?

Comment: In the example sentence you give, it's second person, so it's "score you points".  In a third-person sentence, "He's learning how to program in ABC, which will score him big points with ..."